# Retrieve HTTP Header in Django RestFrameWork

Tags: python, django, http-headers, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework to implement a small function, which is to provide an API for our partners to access some data. The backend has already been written and I'm only writing the API to tap into it to get some data, so I'm just using function-based views to simplify things. Here's my test code:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((BasicAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def get_key(request):
    username = request.user.username
    enc = encode(key, username)
    return Response({'API_key': enc, 'username': username}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):
    user = request.user
    API_key = request.META.get('Authorization') # the value is null
    return Response({'API_key': API_key})
```

So the logged-in user first get an API key by calling `get_key(request)`. Then he uses the API key to get the data. The problem is that I cannot retrieve the key that is put into the `Authorization` header:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'yNd5vdL4f6d4f6dfsdF29DPh9vUtg=='}
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/getdata', headers=headers)
```

So I'm wondering how to get the header fields in django rest framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You need to lookup `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` key instead of `AUTHORIZATION` because Django appends `HTTP_` prefix to the header name.**

From the Django docs on [request.META:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

> With the exception of `CONTENT_LENGTH` and `CONTENT_TYPE`, any HTTP 
>   headers in the request are converted to META keys by
>   converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with
>   underscores **and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name**. So, for example, a
>   header called `X-Bender` would be mapped to the META key `HTTP_X_BENDER`.

So, to retrieve the API key, you need to do:

```
API_key = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
```